# How to generate newsfeed / timeline consisting of different types of contents?

Tags: python, django, polymorphism, timeline

I have to implement a newsfeed for an application where I need to show different types of content. And in the future, some new types of content may come. I have the following idea in my mind at a high level. At this point of time, I'm not concerned about ranking, caching, etc. My focus is to generate newsfeeds having different types of content.

```py
class ContentType1(models.Model):
    pass


class ContentType2(models.Model):
    pass


class ContentType3(models.Model):
    pass


class Content(models.Model):
    c_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=6,
        choices=[
            ('TYPE1', 'Type 1 content'),
            ('TYPE2', 'Type 2 content'),
            ('TYPE3', 'Type 3 content')
        ]
    )

    type_1 = models.ForeignKey(ContentType1, null=True, blank=True)
    type_2 = models.ForeignKey(ContentType2, null=True, blank=True)
    type_3 = models.ForeignKey(ContentType3, null=True, blank=True)
```

The idea is to have a general `Content` model having separate fields for every type of content and a field named `c_type` which determines the type of the content and guides to access the corresponding field. And responding to users' requests from the Content queryset.

I'm not fully satisfied with the approach, looking for a better approach maybe something with polymorphism or any better approach using Django.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the choices field to select the content type.

for example:

```
class Content(models.MOdel):
CONTENT_TYPE=(
    ('type1','Type1'),
    ('type2','Type2'),
    ('type3','Type3'),
    )
#other fields

content_type=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CONTENT_TYPE,default='type1')
body = models.TextField(blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```